# How to review emails markes as phishing in Google Workspace - Alert Center

Tags: google-workspace, google-alerts

I received notification in Google Workspace - Alert Center about "Phishing message".

It says:
"Google detected and reclassified 1 message from noreply@***.com as phishing, post-delivery. This message was not opened and has been removed from recipients' inboxes. There was 1 recipient."

They provide "Message ID", "Subject Hash" and "Message Body Hash".
I spoke to support but they could not explain to me why they provide above if I can not retrieve this message to see it myself.

Is there a way for me as an admin to see those emails and determine myself what this phishing is about? According to Google support person I can not see those emails.

Thanks